# Start program via ssh in Jenkins and using it in Jenkins build

Tags: ssh, jenkins, jmeter

---

Hello people.

I'm using Jenkins as CI server and I need to run some performance test using Jmeter. I've setup the plugin and configured my workspace and everything works ok, but I have to do some steps manually and I want a bit more of "automation".

Currently i have some small programs in a remote server. These programs make some specific validations, for instance (just to explain): validates e-mail addresses, phone numbers, etc.
So, before I run the build in jenkins, I have to manually start the program (file.sh) I want:
I have to use putty (or any othe ssh client) to conect to the server and then run, for instance, the command

```
./email_validation.sh
```

And the Jmeter test runs in a correct way, and when the test is done I have to manually "shut down" the program I started. But what I want is trying to start the program I need in Jenkins configuration (not manually outside Jenkins, but in "execute shell" or "execute remote shell using ssh" build step).

I have tried to start it, but it get stuck, because when Jenkins build finds the command

```
./email_validation.sh
```

the build stops, it waits for the command to finish and then it will continue the other build steps, but obviously, I need this step not to finish until the test is executed.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run your command as a background process by adding the & symbol at the end of the command and use the [nohup command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html) in case the parent process gets a hangup signal, e.g.

```
nohup /path/to/email_validation.sh &
```

If the script produces any output, it will go by default to the file nohup.out in the current directory when the script was launched.

You can kill the process at the end of the build by running:

```
pkill email_validation.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I execute the "pkill" command the process didn't stop. I had to kill it manually, searching and using the PID

Comment: Ok, I've found how to solve. I had to use "pkill -f" and the name of the process inside "file.sh" (the file.sh is a kind of shortcut, inside this file is a big command line. So instead of execute this big command each time, we just run the file.sh)